# Is it possible to sign the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, 2.0 in I already signed 1.1?

Tags: launchpad, community, pgp

I am currently trying to sign the Ubuntu CoC, version 2.0, and I have already signed 1.1. When I visit http://launchpad.net/codeofconduct, I am told:

> The current version is 2.0, released 2005-04-12
>
> Congratulations, you have already signed the Ubuntu Code of Conduct.

Following the link shows a signature for 1.1, using my PGP keys. In addition, I signed 1.1 long after 2005, and 1.1 was reported as the current version. Did I accidentally sign the wrong version, causing me to lock out of the signing system? I don't want to invalidate my current signature, if at all possible.

Comment: I have updated my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also have the same:

```
The current version is 2.0, released 2005-04-12

Congratulations, you have already signed the Ubuntu Code of Conduct.
```

If I click on signed, I get to my Code of Conduct version 1.1 I have signed. You can check it, and at the end you have a Deactivat button.

Click it, and then you can sign it again, using the usual method. This time you will sign the 2.0 version.

P.S. Sorry for the non-detailed answer, but I am in a hurry :)

Edit:

I have managed to revoke my old code of conduct, and now I have signed the 2.0 version.

```
Your Code of Conduct Signature was modified.
= Ubuntu Code of Conduct v2.0 =
```

However I had some small issues;

For starters, I have deleted the old key I have signed the initial COC, so I generated a new one. Strangely when running the command :

```
gpg --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
```

the default key is taken. I had now multiple on my key-ring, so I wasn't signing with the one I had just re-registered on Launchpad's site.
The correct command to sign the COC with the chosen key is:

```
gpg -u <name of wanted key> --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
```

So when I finally managed to sign the COC with the wanted key, Launchpad wasn't accepting the response I was generating. Honestly I have copy/pasted the response at least 15 times, until it finally accepted it. :)

So there I go, now I have version 2.0 signed.